# data.table rowwise operations using a column lookahead

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, boolean

Suppose I have the following data:

```
        tempmat=matrix(c(1,1,0,4,1,0,0,4,0,1,0,4, 0,1,1,4, 0,1,0,5),5,4,byrow=T)
        tempmat=rbind(rep(0,4),tempmat)
        tempmat=data.table(tempmat)
        names(tempmat)=paste0('prod1vint',1:4)
        tempmat[,firstnonzero:=c(NA,1,1,2,2,2)]
```

So the data table looks like this:

```
> tempmat
   prod1vint1 prod1vint2 prod1vint3 prod1vint4 firstnonzero
1:          0          0          0          0           NA
2:          1          1          0          4            1
3:          1          0          0          4            1
4:          0          1          0          4            2
5:          0          1          1          4            2
6:          0          1          0          5            2
```

I want to find the number of nonzero elements to the right of the column indicated by "firstnonzero".

The desired output would be:

```
> tempmat
   prod1vint1 prod1vint2 prod1vint3 prod1vint4 firstnonzero numbernonzero
1:          0          0          0          0           NA            NA
2:          1          1          0          4            1             2
3:          1          0          0          4            1             1
4:          0          1          0          4            2             1
5:          0          1          1          4            2             2
6:          0          1          0          5            2             1
```

This is because, for example, on row 2, there is a nonzero element in prod1vint2 and prod1vint4, so the number of nonzero elements to the right of the first nonzero element is 2, and so forth.

I am trying to fin a solution that is efficient and scales well, so it cannot be an apply or looping style solution, which I could implement myself.

Comment: `mapply(function(x, y) if(!is.na(y)) {
  x <- as.integer(x)
  sum(x[(y+1):length(x)] != 0, na.rm = TRUE) 
  } else NA,
       split(tempmat[,1:4], 1:nrow(tempmat)), tempmat$firstnonzero)` this works but I doubt if it fits your "efficiency" criteria. There should be a better solution though.

Comment: efficiency..it is hard, If I were you , I will melt first , then group_by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the suggestion from the comments to reshape from wide to long. Not sure how this compares but it might be a start.

```
dcast(melt(tempmat[, n := 1L:.N], id.vars = c("firstnonzero", "n"))[,
    `:=`(
        firstnonzero = which(value != 0L)[1],
        numbernonzero = length(which(value != 0L)[-1])),
    by = n],
    n + firstnonzero + numbernonzero ~ variable)[, n := NULL][]
#   firstnonzero numbernonzero prod1vint1 prod1vint2 prod1vint3 prod1vint4
#1:           NA             0          0          0          0          0
#2:            1             2          1          1          0          4
#3:            1             1          1          0          0          4
#4:            2             1          0          1          0          4
#5:            2             2          0          1          1          4
#6:            2             1          0          1          0          5
```

Note: In order to make this work with the sample data you provided, I had to make the existing `tempmat$firstnonzero` column an integer vector (see sample data at the end).

In order to benchmark this it would be useful if you had included (some of) the "*apply or looping style solution, which I could implement myself*".

---

### Sample data

```
tempmat=matrix(c(1,1,0,4,1,0,0,4,0,1,0,4, 0,1,1,4, 0,1,0,5),5,4,byrow=T)
tempmat=rbind(rep(0,4),tempmat)
tempmat=data.table(tempmat)
names(tempmat)=paste0('prod1vint',1:4)
tempmat[,firstnonzero:=c(NA,1L,1L,2L,2L,2L)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are calculating quite a number of statistics for each row, you might want to consider using `Rcpp` as follows:

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('
IntegerMatrix func(IntegerMatrix m) {
    int i, j, nr = m.nrow(), nc = m.ncol();
    IntegerMatrix res(nr, 3);

    for (i=0; i<nr; i++) {
        res(i, 0) = -1;     //position
        res(i, 1) = -1;     //count
        res(i, 2) = 0;      //sum

        for (j=0; j<nc; j++) {
            if (m(i, j) != 0) {
                if (res(i, 0) < 0) {
                    res(i, 0) = j + 1;
                }

                if (res(i, 1) >= 0) {
                    res(i, 2) += m(i, j);
                }

                res(i, 1) += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return res;    
}')

tempmat = matrix(c(1,1,0,4,1,0,0,4,0,1,0,4, 0,1,1,4, 0,1,0,5),5,4,byrow=T)
tempmat = rbind(rep(0,4),tempmat)
cbind(tempmat, func(tempmat))
```

output:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    0    0    0    0   -1   -1    0
[2,]    1    1    0    4    1    2    5
[3,]    1    0    0    4    1    1    4
[4,]    0    1    0    4    2    1    4
[5,]    0    1    1    4    2    2    5
[6,]    0    1    0    5    2    1    5
```

This should be quite fast.